# Arraylist list.get() prints memory address instead of value (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

this is my first question here! I am trying to print a formatted grid of numbers. I did it with a 2D array just fine, but when I tried doing it with an array list, I couldn't.

I initialized an array list that takes an arraylist of integers and inputted the values using an array because I didn't know a better way to add a lot of elements (don't you have to add each individually using .add("number here")?) Anyways

Here is the code for the 2D array and the 2D arraylist

```
 public static void print2Darray() {
    int[][] array = {{10, 15, 30, 40}, {15, 5, 8, 2}, {20, 2, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 0}};
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


public static void print2DList() {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] array = {{10, 15, 30, 40}, {15, 5, 8, 2}, {20, 2, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 0}};
    List list2 = Arrays.asList(array);
    list.addAll(list2);
    System.out.println (list2.get(2)); //this prints the memory address (how can I print the number instead?)
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list2.toArray()));


    }
}
```

If I figure out how to print the line before the last correctly, I can specify loop four times for every line and print the values. But, `list2.get()` gets the memory address instead of the value.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `Arrays.toString((int[])list2.get(2))`

Comment: You're creating a `List<int[]>`. `int[]` doesn't override `toString`. Just use `Arrays.toString(list2.get(2))` - after setting the type of `list2` to `List<int[]>` to avoid using raw types.

Comment: It's not a memory address, but the Hashcode. See how short it is!

Comment: Yes @dasblinkenlight! Thank you. I tried casting it (I believe this is what it is called.) But, it didn't work because I casted it to `int` and not `int[]`